# Is there a way to easily loop through objects?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, class, loops, object

I want to check an objects list of coordinates against every other list of coordinates. This is how I wrote it before: All these are `Ship` objects, and `CheckForCollisions` is in the `Ship` class.

```
'AIR CRAFT CARRIER
 If AirCraftCarrier.has_moved And Battleship.has_moved Then
    AirCraftCarrier.CheckForCollisions(Battleship)
 ElseIf AirCraftCarrier.has_moved And Submarine.has_moved Then
    AirCraftCarrier.CheckForCollisions(Submarine)
 ElseIf AirCraftCarrier.has_moved And Destroyer.has_moved Then
    AirCraftCarrier.CheckForCollisions(Destroyer)
 ElseIf AirCraftCarrier.has_moved And PatrolBoat.has_moved Then
    AirCraftCarrier.CheckForCollisions(PatrolBoat)
 End If

'BATTLESHIP
If Battleship.has_moved And AirCraftCarrier.has_moved Then
    Battleship.CheckForCollisions(AirCraftCarrier)
ElseIf Battleship.has_moved And Submarine.has_moved Then
    Battleship.CheckForCollisions(Submarine)
ElseIf Battleship.has_moved And Destroyer.has_moved Then
    Battleship.CheckForCollisions(Destroyer)
ElseIf Battleship.has_moved And PatrolBoat.has_moved Then
    Battleship.CheckForCollisions(PatrolBoat)
End If
'etc., there's 3 more that look exactly this this.
```

But I would definitely rather do this using a loop. This also didn't even work. It would only check the first ship (the AirCraftCarrier object) and then ignore the rest. Only ships that collided with the ACC would register, if they collided with eachother, nothing would happen.

This is an example I wrote to try and implement this myself. I was thinking about using the ids and looping through them but I couldn't figure out how to do it. Is there a concept that you guys could introduce to me that you think would help me?

```
Public Class Main
    Dim acc As Ship
    Dim bs As Ship
    Dim sm As Ship
    Dim ds As Ship
    Dim pb As Ship

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        acc = New Ship(1, {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}, {1, 6}})
        bs = New Ship(2, {{0, 4}, {1, 4}, {2, 4}, {3, 4}})
        sm = New Ship(3, {{4, 5}, {4, 6}, {4, 7}})
        ds = New Ship(4, {{3, 6}, {4, 6}, {5, 6}})
        pb = New Ship(5, {{7, 7}, {7, 8}})
    End Sub

End Class
Public Class Ship

    Dim _id As Integer
    Public Property id() As Integer
        Get
            Return _id
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _id = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Dim _magnitude(,) As Integer
    Public Property magnitude As Integer(,)
        Get
            Return _magnitude
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer(,))
            _magnitude = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New(ByVal idp As Integer, ByVal magnitudep As Integer(,))
        id = idp
        magnitude = magnitudep
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: rather than checking for a collisions with each ship, if you had a GameBoard class which knew where each ship was, you could check with it to see if there was any another ship in the destination **before** it moved. Otherwise, you could store the ships in a List, and iterate the list based on the one that just moved.  You might want to look into Inheritance - a BattleShip class ought to know its own stats rather than being told that stuff in the ctor.  Inheritance would allow a Submarine class which was a Type of Ship to implement just the stuff unique to subs, like torpedoes.

Comment: How could I make the game board know the location of each ship? I briefly thought about trying that but I couldn't figure out how.

Comment: The board would have a static array of 128x128 (?), when a ship wants to move it does `GameBrd.CheckMove(x, y)` if true it can move there; then after the move `.ShipMoved(Me, x, y)` and the Game, marks that location as occupied by the ship identified.  The Game class could handle other things like `IsInRangeOf`.  Very much depends on whether the point is to write a game or learn programming.

Comment: having watched this grow the last 2-3 days, I have to ask: what the heck is magnitude?

Comment: A list of points that the ships take up in the board. I could not think of a better name...

Comment: in that case, those arrays could be replaced by a simple `Size` object: 1x6, 3x1, 1x3, 2x1, 1x2 (I think).  The Game class could then create a Rect from it based on a ship's direction and current X,Y.  Collision check then is VERY simple using the `IntersectsWith` function of `Rectangle`.  Game just has to loop thru the List(Of Ships) and see if the rectangle  for `thisShip.IntersectsWith` that of any other ship's rectangle.

Comment: Ohhh, I've never heard of that! That's really helpful thanks!

Comment: I don't think Rectangle.IntersectsWith is working properly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665519/rectangle-intersetswith-returning-true-whenever-the-two-rectangles-are-on-the

Answer (score 1):

Could you do something like this?

```
'A list of all the ships
Dim ships As Ship() = _
    { AirCraftCarrier, Battleship, Submarine, _
        Destroyer, PatrolBoat}

Dim query = _
    From ship1 in ships ' iterate thru the ships
    From ship2 in ships ' iterate thru the ships
    Where ship1 <> ship2 ' keep only if both ships are not the same ship
    Where ship1.has_moved 'keep if ship1 has moved
    Where ship2.has_moved 'keep if ship2 has moved
    Select New With { ship1, ship2 }

For Each s in query
    ' for each pair of moved ships check for collision
    s.ship1.CheckForCollisions(s.ship2)
Next
```

Comment: Could you explain that a bit? I don't completely understand.

Comment: A little. What does the underscore in the list of ships mean?

Comment: line continuation character

Comment: It just lets you continue it on the next line?