# Rectangle.IntersetsWith() returning true whenever the two rectangles are on the same X axis

Tags: arrays, vb.net, loops, geometry, collision-detection

I'm trying to recreate Battleship and I'm using Rectangle.IntersectsWith() to find collisions between each ship. Whenever I put the ships on the same x axis on the grid, the function returns true. It doesn't if they are on the same y axis or if they are touching.

This is the code I use to test every ship against every other ship (If you know of an easier way, I'd love to hear about it).

```
Public Sub CheckForCollision()
    Dim ships As Ship() = _
        {AirCraftCarrier, Battleship, Submarine, _
            Destroyer, PatrolBoat}

    For i As Integer = 0 To 4
        Dim ship1 As Ship = ships(i)
        For j As Integer = 0 To 4
            Dim ship2 As Ship = ships(j)
            If ship1.name <> ship2.name Then
                If ship1.rect.IntersectsWith(ship2.rect) Then
                    Debug.Print(ship1.name & " and " & ship2.name & " intersect")
                End If

            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

The rects x and y values are changed whenever the ship is moved to a new spot. I just set it to PictureBox location.

Comment: How do these guys move, mouse drag?  The X,Y you are storing might be the wrong reference.  The X,Y (point) can be relative to the Form, Screen or PictureBox depending on how you get them.  Form(10,20) <> PictureBox(10, 20).  How did the `rects` get initialized, if they have the wrong H or W, it will report wrong too.

Comment: The mouse drags it to the screen and then the top left corner gets set to the top left of which ever box its sitting on.

Comment: Ah that was the problem! I mixed up the H and W. Thanks, again!

Answer (score 0):

Testing for a collison on a specific ship:

```
Public Function SoundCollision(thisShip As Ship) as Boolean
    Dim ships As Ship() = _
        {AirCraftCarrier, Battleship, Submarine, _
            Destroyer, PatrolBoat}

    Dim bRet as Boolean = False          ' assume not

    For n As Integer = 0 To 4
        If ships(n).Name <> thisShip.Name Then
            If thisShip.rect.IntersectsWith(ships(n).rect) Then
                bret = true
                Debug.Print(ships(n).name & " intersects " & thisShip.name)
                Exit For            ' skip the rest
            End If

        End If
    Next
    Return bRet
End Sub
```

If it is method in your Ship class, use Me instead of thisShip and dont pass it

Comment: I have another question maybe you can help with?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667403/boolean-being-set-to-false-whenever-it-is-accessed-again