# Boolean being set to False whenever it is accessed again?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, list, boolean

Whenever I try to operate on a variable, it instantly gets set to false. This method is supposed to turn the `full` property on the `box` object stored in `box_list` to True. It finds the correct boxes and changes the property, but whenever it is accessed again, it turns to false.

```
Public Sub DefineFilled()
    Dim ship As New Ship(Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing)
    Dim x As Integer = 0
    Dim y As Integer = 0

    ship = AirCraftCarrier
    If ship.has_moved Then
        Debug.Print("")
        For i As Integer = 0 To ship.length - 1
            x = ship.space_filled(i, 0) 'space_filled is a list that stores each point that the ship takes up on the grid
            y = ship.space_filled(i, 1) 
            PlayerBoard.box_list(x, y).full = True 'Sets variable to True

            Debug.Print(PlayerBoard.box_list(x, y).full) 'Prints variable as False
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

**Edit 1: PlayerBoard definition**

(In Main)

```
Public PlayerBoard As Board

Private Sub Main_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    PlayerBoard = New Board(tile_size, 330, Color.Silver)
End Sub
```

(Board class)

```
Public Class Board
    Dim _box_list(,) as Box
    Public Property box_list() As Box(,)
        Get
            Return _box_list
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Box(,))
            _box_list = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New(ByVal pos_x As Integer, ByVal pos_y As Integer, ByVal colourp As Color)
        ReDim _box_list(10, 10)
    End Sub
```

**Edit 2: How box_list is defined (In board class)**

```
Private Sub BuildBoard()

    For y As Integer = 0 To 9
        For x As Integer = 0 To 9
            Dim box As New Box(x, y, New PictureBox)
            With box
                .image.Location = New Point(start_location(0) + x * tile_size, start_location(1) + y * tile_size)
                .image.Size = New Size(tile_size, tile_size)
                .image.BackColor = colour
                .image.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
            End With
            box_list(x, y) = box
            Main.Controls.Add(box_list(x, y).image)
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

**Edit 3: Definition of box**

```
Public Class Box
    Dim _image As PictureBox
    Public Property image() As PictureBox
        Get
            Return _image
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As PictureBox)
            _image = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Dim _full As Boolean
    Public Property full() As Boolean
        Get
            Return _full
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            _full = full
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New(ByVal location_x As Integer, ByVal location_y As Integer, ByVal imagep As PictureBox)
        image = imagep
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: We need to see the definition of whatever type PlayerBoard is, especially the box_list function.

Comment: Added. Hope I got everything that's relevant.

Comment: Side issue: Get rid of the Set option for your box_list() property. You don't want it. You will still be able to change elements in that array after removing the Set.

Comment: Also: `status_norepro`. Sample program I built with this code works as expected. There's something else you're not showing us... perhaps re-declaring your object instance.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn But I need to write to it as well. Or did I misunderstand you? Also what is status_norepro?

Comment: @alexanderd5398 you can still make changes to elements in the array without a Set. The only thing you can't do is replace the entire array in one assignment. For example, this will still work without a setter: `PlayerBoard.box_list(x, y).full = True`. So will this: `PlayerBoard.box_list(x, y) = New Box()`. Both of those only use the **Get** option. But this won't work: `PlayerBoard.box_list = New Box(9,9)`. Understanding why this is will go a long way towards helping you understand how Objects really work.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Awesome thanks! I added what I thought you meant by "re-declaring your object instance".

Comment: You also need to add the definition of `Box` as this seems to be where the error is happening.

Comment: @Enigmativity Added. Wow. I'm not very good at asking questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem with this code is in the `full` property on the `Box` class.

You have it written like this now:

```
Public Property full() As Boolean
    Get
        Return _full
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        _full = full
    End Set
End Property
```

It should be this:

```
Public Property full() As Boolean
    Get
        Return _full
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        _full = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Your current code is recursively setting the property back to its own value. Hence it is staying `false`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I can't believe I missed that :/

Comment: No problem. Sometimes it's the little things that trip us up.